# nimbus-jose-jwt Plugin Type Not Found Error

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I am trying to compile code sample from this book ([Play Framework Cookbook 2nd Edition)](https://www.packtpub.com/web-development/play-framework-cookbook-second-edition) for JWT with nimbus-jose-jwt.

However it said `Plugin` trait type not found during compilation.  I checked API documentation, `Plugin` is available at `play.api` package.

```
import play.api.{Logger, Play, Application, Plugin}
class JWTPlugin @Inject() (app: Application) extends Plugin {...}
```

I tried DI version with and without 
`routesGenerator :=  InjectedRoutesGenerator` at `build.sbt` with same error.

nimbus-jose-jwt version: 3.8.2.  Tried with latest 4.22, with same error.

scala: 2.11.8

play: 2.5.4

Appreciate any pointer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

play.api.Plugin has been removed in Play 2.5.x. You can turn the plugin into a Module instead as described here: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/PluginsToModules

But the easiest solution is to turn the JWTPlugin class into a plain Scala object (e.g. JWTUtil), remove the onStart and onStop methods, remove the "private val jwt" declarations/assigments from all files in the example and call the sign() and verify() methods on the JWTUtil object instead.

Maybe you need some more minor modifications that I have forgotten, but anyway, the example works for me when the JWT implementation doesn't inherit from play.api.Plugin.